# Variable scope with `import().then()` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, scope

I'm writing a JS function that import a module:

```
load (path) {

    let index = 5;
    import(path)
        .then((data) => {
             console.log(path);
             console.log(index);
        })
}
```

The above code display the path, but generate an error for `index`:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'index' before initialization

I don't understand why the variable `path` is in the scope of the promise, but not `index`?

How to get `index` in the scope of the promise?

Comment: `index` is in scope in your example. Are you maybe redeclaring it somewhere else in your `.then()` callback? PS: you're missing a `)` after the second last `}` in your snippet

Comment: You are awesome! I re-declared `index` later in the code